# Strange Json.net exception "Input string was not in a correct format."

Tags: c#, parsing, windows-phone-7, json.net

I have 2 quite complicated objects, one is parsing successfully, and other is throwing exception. The only difference between objects is 2 double-type properties. I'm deserializing it as

```
var item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyItem>(result.ToString());
```

Where `MyItem` holds both lines, so in first case they should be empty (item doesn't hold them), and in second case they should be set (as they exist in json and in deserialization object).

Trace:

```
at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ConvertUtils.IntParseFast(Char[] value, Int32 start, Int32 length)
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseNumber()
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadInternal()
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadAsInt32Internal()
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadAsInt32()
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(JsonReader reader, JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please post the JSON you're parsing (`result.ToString()`) in each case. A short but *complete* example would be ideal.

Comment: Do post the `MyItem` class and both JSON strings.

Comment: @JonSkeet Holy crap, guys, i should go and sell some hamburgers :) While copying diff part, i found that one of the properties was set as int...

Comment: This is why it's a good idea to come up with a short but complete program before you even post the question - it's amazing how it focuses the mind ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check format of your serialized object according to primitives types of your composite object. And also use this part of code

```
var item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyItem>(result.ToString(),
new JsonSerializerSettings(){DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore});
```